# Client liberary Producer to send Message to KAFKA broker in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am building a project where Project Target Frame work is  .NET Framework 4.0, i cannot go with .NET FrameWork 4.5. Can you suggest me any KAFKA client library for  publishing message to KAKFA broker that supports .NET 4.0

Currently i am calling python script from c# to publish data to kakfa, but its taking time, as i need to push data immediately one after other, so am looking for dll in c#. i googled out , but could not find one that supports .net 4.

Comment: Why can't you use .NET Framework 4.5? Most of the good libraries need > 4.0.